# C#: Use of references

Tags: c#, reference

I have a form (form1) with a button (Button1) on.

Why does example 1 change text properties on Button1 to "CHANGED" on form1, but example 2 does not? Why is there a difference?

Example 1:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication35
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button b1 = new Button();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            b1 = button1;
            b1.Text = "CHANGED";
        }
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication35
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button b1 = new Button();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1 = b1;
            b1.Text = "CHANGED";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Append this.Controls.Add(b1); to the constructor so you can actually see the side-effects of the code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button you have on screen has two parts to it, the "object" in memory on the heap and a reference to the memory on the heap which is what the variable `button1` holds.

Inside `InitializeComponent();` the function `this.Controls.Add(button1)` will get called. What this will do is it will add another reference to the "object" inside the memory of `this.Controls`.

When you did `b1 = button1;` you made the reference stored in the variable `b1` point at the object that was created with `button1` then when you did `b1.Text = "CHANGED";` you where calling `.Text` on the object that the variables `b1`, `button1`, and the reference inside `this.Controls` all pointed at.

When you did `button1 = b1;` you made the reference stored in the variable `button1` point at the object that was created with `b1`. Now at this point you have `b1` and `button1` pointing at the object created with `b1` and the reference stored inside `this.Controls` is still pointing at the object that was created with `button1` and is now the only reference pointing at that object. When you did `b1.Text = "CHANGED";` you where calling `.Text` on the object that the variables `b1` and  `button1` pointed at but you did not update the object `this.Controls` pointed at.

And the final piece of the puzzle is the objects whose references are stored in `this.Controls` are the things that get rendered on screen. That is why the screen did not update.

Answer (score 1):

It is because button1 is defined in the designer and so it gets rendered in the auto generated code for the form, while the other button is only instantiated but not associated to any form.

Answer (score 0):

In example 1, after creating a `Button` and assigning `b1` to point to it, you're *re*assigning `b1` to point to the same actual `Button` as `button1`.  Since the `button1` Button is on the form, you can see it change.

In example 2, you're doing the reverse: you're creating a `Button` which `b1` points to, and then you're pointing `button1` at that same nebulous button.  That button was never added to the form's Controls collection, so you can't see it on the form.

Have a look at the code in the `InitializeComponent` method (use Go to Definition) to see what happens to `button1` that your `b1` doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
Button b1 = new Button();
```

You are only creating an instance of `Button` and storing it in memory. `b1` will not be displayed on the screen until you add it to the controls of the form:

```
Controls.Add(b1);
```

In Example 1, you did this:

```
b1 = button1;
```

This means that you change the value of `b1` to the value stored in `button1`. I assume this `button1` here is something generated by the Windows Forms Designer, so it is added to the screen in the `InitializeComponents` method.

Before the above line is run, `b1` stores a (reference to a) button that doesn't appear on the screen. After the line is run, `b1` stores a (reference to a) button that does appear on the screen. This is why you can see the change of text after you set the text of `b1`.

In Example 2, you did this:

```
button1 = b1;
```

You change the value of `button1` to `b1`.

Then this line is run:

```
b1.Text = "CHANGED";
```

Since `b1` still stores a (reference to a) button that doesn't appear on the screen, you can't see the text of `b1` change.